# Exporting Android library project resources under different package name?

Tags: android, android-library

I'm not sure whether I'm running into a bug in the Android tools here, or whether this is by design. The problem is this: I have an Android library project that exports a widget. As part of that widget, styleable attributes are exported in R.styleable:

Library project (package = com.example.mylib):

```
<declare-styleable name="com.example.MyWidget">
    <attr name="someAttr" format="integer" />
</declare-styleable>
```

App project (package = com.example.myapp):

```
<LinearLayout xmnls:mylib="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.mylib">
  <com.example.MyWidget android:id="..." mylib:someAttr="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is, the `someAttr` attribute seems to be only visible to Android/ADT whenever the library and the application use the same package identifier! In this case, they don't, and the ADT fail with the following error:

> No resource identifier found for attribute 'someAttr' in package 'com.example.mylib'

Like I said I can fix this by changing the app's package name to "com.example.mylib", but of course this is not what I want! Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug [#9656](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9656). I've written two posts about this issue: [here](http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/05/22/236/) and [here](http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/05/22/the-case-of-android-libraries-and-custom-xml-attributes-part-2/). I've explained why this happens and how to patch aapt to fix this issue if you really-really need this fixed right now.

For now, if you do not want to rebuild aapt, you need to move all you custom attributes and layouts that use those custom attributes from library to application.

Comment: Oh my, well, now I'd like to have those two hours of my life back that I wasted trying to wrap my head around this. Thanks!

Comment: Actually I have a question about this: when I copy the attrs.xml from the lib project to the app project, then the resource IDs will mismatch at runtime and the app will crash. When I move it, then the lib project won't even compile anymore. So how exactly can I fix this by copying the styleable declarations?

Comment: You need to move everything that *uses* custom xml attriubtes to application, not only custom attribute declaration. In other words, if you had custom View X that was using custom attributes, and layouts L1,..,Ln that used custom view X, then you need to move view X and all Ls to application project.

Comment: actually I discovered a workaround that doesn't require one to do that. See my response on the Android bug tracker.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that might be still looking for the answer: since ADT 17 you have to use *http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto* as namespace for custom attributes in library projects, works as a charm:

```
xmnls:mylib="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```